# Harry Potter text- What does “one’s mind is going” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, american-english

In the last few lines of Lily’s letter to Sirius Black (The book Harry Potter), she wrote:

> I don't know how much to believe, actually, because it seems incredible that Dumbledore could ever have been friends with Gellert Grindelwald. I think her mind's going, personally!

What does “her mind is going” mean here?

I tried to google but failed to find relevant information, is it a not-so-common phrase? If so, wonder what’s the more commonly used phrase in the similar meaning.

Comment: Especially with respect to older people it means they are becoming senile.

Answer (score 0):

It means that her mind is going wrong, that she is losing her mind, that she is behaving foolishly. It is a common expression.

Comment: Yeah, she's "going out of her mind".

Comment: Losing one's mind and behaving foolishly are two different things, although losing one's mind might result in foolish behaviour.

Comment: @nnnnnn - But the two are often equated metaphorically.

Comment: @HotLicks - Yes, that's true. Though in the context of the quote in the question it seems to be meant more literally, perhaps referring to the onset of dementia.